# mysqlcheck causing server issue using 100% cpu, server not responsive

Tags: mysql, database, cpu-usage

I have a mysql server (5.0.58) that is hosting many databases (~30). A few years ago I started running into performance problems with some db which I eventually resolved by executing a nightly cron job to check/optimize the database using the following command:

```
mysqlcheck --check --auto-repair --analyze --optimize --silent --all-databases
```

This command normally executes in ~ 20 minutes. This worked like a charm, until last month. When this command executes now, the CPU on the machine spikes and the machine becomes almost unresponsive. The only thing I can do is restart the mysqld service (after waiting 10-15 minutes just to log in). In looking at the mysql process list when this is happening, it seems that some tables may also be locked, but I am still researching this.

Anyone have any idea on why this command would be locking up the server? I am planning to try to limit the command to specific databases (as opposed to --all-databases) to see if this helps.

Comment: For future reference, database questions do not belong here, there is a subsite designed for them.  Get a login and post future questions on http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions and you will get much higher reception.

Comment: The current version of MySQL is 5.5, you report 5.0.58.  It could be a bug in the software, and updating to the latest version might clear up your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Why is mysqlcheck bogging down the computer?**

Maybe you exhausted all available RAM and mysql is starting to use virtual swap space instead which requires lots of disk reads/writes and uses up all the CPU. Test this theory by adding RAM or doing mysqlcheck on fewer databases at once.

Maybe you've filled up your hard drive space and processes have to wait for available hard drive space because all of it has been reserved (even if the drive isn't completely full).  Test this theory by freeing hard drive space.

Perhaps your CPU's are thrashing, meaning most of the work the CPU's are doing are switching between tasks instead of performing the tasks.  Try doing the command on each individual database sequentially.

**Workarounds:**

Try running `mysqlcheck` at a lower priority so that you can still log in and it doesn't prevent other processes from running. It depends on what operating system you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Eric. I verified that there is plenty of disk space available, but have not looked at RAM while this command is running. I will try that soon. I will also use your suggestion of running at a lower priority. I am fairly certain that running the command on individual databases will help (I have run these manually a few times already), but it is sort of inconvenient. Still, it might be the best workaround. I will try some of these and let you know how it goes. Thanks!